# get_the_content returns an array as string - how to get plain text out of it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the Jevelin theme for wordpress and I'm about to customize the `search.php` which calls the `content.php`.

When searching something on my website and a normal page is found, I want to display like 200 characters of the content in plain text. But this `echo wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);` returns me an array (I think) as a string and I don't know why.

It looks something like:

`[section id="75c1f1dc25182497ebcc66dabf9ce8a5" width="standard" padding="0" padding_mobile="{"padding_mobile":"off","on":{"padding":"60px 0px 60px 0px"}}" columns_height="" visibility="everywhere" elememt_alignment="default" strech_edge="disabled" background_image="" background="{"background_type":"none","none":{"background_image_options":"cover"},"parallax":{"parallax_options":""},"parallax_video":{"parallax_video_url":""},"video":{"mp4_url":"","webm_url":"","ogv_url":""}}" background_color="#ffffff" background_color_overlay="" border_radius="" margin="0px 0px 0px 0px" margin_mobile="{"margin_mobile":"off","on":{"margin":"0px 0px 0px 0px"}}"` ... and so on.

**search.php**

```
<ul class="search-list list-unstyled">
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            if( get_post_format() ) :
              get_template_part( 'content', 'format-'.get_post_format() );
                    else :
                        get_template_part( 'content' );
                    endif;

                endwhile;
            else :

                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
?>
</ul>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
/* Layout for search results */
elseif( $style == 'search-results' ) :
?>

<li>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
    <strong class="block"><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
    <p>
     <?php 
      if(has_excerpt()) {
        get_the_excerpt();  
      }
      else {
        $content = get_the_content();
        echo $content;
        echo wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);
      }         

    ?>
    <span class="read-more">[more]</span>
    </p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case

```
<?= strip_tags(do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID()))) ?>
```

was the working solution

Answer (score 1):

Its not an array its a short code , change content.php like below:

```
<?php 
      if(has_excerpt()) {
        get_the_excerpt();  
      }
      else {
        $content = get_the_content();
        echo do_shortcode($content); // HERE: $content changed to do_shortcode($content);
        //echo wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);
      }         

    ?>
```

Comment: This outputs the content of the page with html (divs, headings and such) but I want it to display as plain text. Is this possible?

Comment: The long string I posted is the post_content with all the information which comes by the page builder of my theme

Comment: @Insane Yes it possible ->  `$content = do_shortcode($content); echo wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);`